# grouping of bits in matlab

Tags: matlab, bit

I have a question regarding bits in matlab. For example, a=101010101011111001. Here, I want to make group of 8 bits at a time from 'a' and obtain its bin2dec form and save it in another form say b.

'a' has three groups : first= 10101010, second=10111110, third=01.

'b' will have the bin2dec of these groups. I want it to be, b=[170 190 1]. I want to do it for large file having bits where it is not possible for me to do make groups own my own (unlike i made in above example) . Considering matlab loops and all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are reading from a file, why not just use the `fread` function ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use reshape! bin2dec takes an entire array.

```
a = '10101001111101010110000001111110010101111001011110011011';
b = bin2dec(reshape(a,8,[])')
b =

   169
   245
    96
   126
    87
   151
   155
```

All in one line too.

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is a number, just add:

```
a = num2str(a);
```

EDIT:

Well if I got you right, you want:

```
a = '1010100111110101011000000111111001010111100101111001';
thesize = ceil(length(a)/8);
b = zeros(1,thesize);
for i = 1:thesize
    b(i) = bin2dec(a(((i-1)*8+1):min(length(a),(i*8)+1)));
end
```

Comment: I want all this to happen by using some loop, where i have no idea how many bits are there,like in large number of bits. Thanks

Comment: Well then edit your post and give a more proper example, because no one will be able to help you with the information you provided

Comment: Don't call variables with names like size! This is a guaranteed way to have malicious bugs later on.